# CPU load on Google Glass

Tags: android, google-glass

I'm having performance issues with Glass. When running my application, and then executing top, I see that about 40% of the processing is used for IRQ handling. Even when shutting down my application, and shutting the screen off, there is still about 10-15% CPU load for IRQs. Testing similar test on a tablet gives me 0%.
Can someone verify these numbers? Does anyone have any idea what is the root cause?

Comment: I can verify that I have similar - I'm seeing IRQ be steady around 17%.